# How to recover / merge partions into Elementary OS?

Tags: dual-boot, disk-management

Let me try and explain the situation:

I used dual-boot with Ubuntu 14/16 and Elementary OS. However, I want to get rid of Ubuntu and either:
1) Install some other distro and try it out, or
2) Preferably, capture/merge the partition space into Elementary OS, so that my Elementary has more space

I have installed Gparted and tried few things but It was a close call. So approaching the forum to find a safe way to add this additional space to the Elementary (and make it the primary and only OS in the system)

Can somebody help/guide in how to do it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Will you please provide more details like which os is installed first, or atleast add screenshot of your gparted window  to your question

Answer (score 1):

To use full functionality of Gparted you need to start it not from your OS. For example, in situations like yours I use Live-USB with Elementary.
So, you run Gparted from Live-USB (or DVD, it's not important) and will see smth like it:[image]

You choose partition with Ubuntu (Windows in my case) and click "Change size/move" (not exact translation because I use Gparted in Russian).Or, if you want to merge your Ubuntu partition, you need to delete Ubuntu partition and change the size of Elementary partition after that.[image]

In that dialog you can change your partition size by changing "size", "free space before" and "free space after" colums.